# Samba for second harddrive

Tags: samba

I found some instructions to set up a samba share so Windows can see my folders. These two instructions work but only for a single drive in Ubuntu. I have a second drive installed in Ubuntu as `sdb1` but don't know what the path should be or what to edit the `smb.config` file to. I made a folder on the `sdb1` drive and called it `test`.

```
[global]
  server string = File Server
  workgroup = NAMEOFWORKGROUP
  security = user
  map to guest = Bad User
  name resolve order = bcast host
  include = /etc/samba/shares.conf

  [Public Files]
  path = /share/public_files
  force user = smbuser
  force group = smbgroup
  create mask = 0664
  force create mode = 0664
  directory mask = 0775
  force directory mode = 0775
  public = yes
  writable = yes
```

Comment: please mind following : it is different if you put M$ as master and linux as slave - this would be not productive for Linux. It would be easier, when you put Linux in place of sda and M$ in place of sdb. Otherwise you would have more frickle things to do. Anyway - dual-boot is dangerous. It would be like "double-head business".

Comment: Three questions for you: (1) are you running Apparmor on Ubuntu? If so, there’s an additional step you need. (2) Do you want `sdb1` to be a separate samba share, or would you like them to appear as one? (3) Would you like to use all of `sdb1` for samba, or just some directories you choose?

Comment: Where is the sdb1filesystem  mounted?  you can create a new share by adding a new definition in smb.conf - eg  [sdbfiles], set the location with  path = /sdbmountpoint/   and the appropriate permissions then it will appear as a share.

Comment: @dschinn1001 why is dual-boot dangerous?

Comment: @OrganicMarble - well, at moment Apple OS-X is not finish (the versions after High Sierra) and M$ is not finish too ? (Windows 10 is still not completed with its updates over and over. So when you do dual-boot - it is like "bills of exchange" with different OS and it can be then polymorphic too each sides. On your PC (interaction between hard-disks partitions).

Comment: I will try this command as suggested.           /sdbmountpoint/ I am just running the server edition of the Ubuntu Sdb1 probably should be a separate share.  I'm not dual booting anything. Just want the data that is on the second harddrive to be seen by windows it can be just one share for all the data on that drive. Regarding the question of where is the sdb1 filesystem mounted. I don't understand what you mean. The data is on the sdb1 drive. I think I need to do a course in samba.

Comment: If you really are using Ubuntu Server and the sdb1 partition is mounted you must have a mount declaration in /etc/fstab. Edit your original post and add the output of this command: `cat /etc/fstab` If for some reason you have no mount declaration in fstab for this partition post the output of this command: `sudo blkid -c /dev/null -o list`

Comment: I cannot copy and paste from linux into windows sorry because its on another computer

Comment: I ran this command lsblk (from the $) and I can see sdb 1.8T 0 disk then the next line is sdb1 1.8T 0 Part how do I view the contents of sdb1 part

Comment: Then I ran this command $ sudo fdisk -l and got /dev/sdb1 showing start, end, sectors, size, ID and the type is linux. I still don't know how to tell what files or directories are on sdb1

Comment: If I change the path in the shares.conf file to be path =  /sdbmountpoint/nameoffolder  windows cannot connect